# tesseract,js error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning / tesseract

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, ocr, tesseract

I'm using tesseract within my node app. The first time the program runs fine.

In this example, foo() repeats it self. From the first repition on, an error is returned (shown below the code)

Could you give me a hint what I have done wrong which doesn't allow this to run a second time? I have tried to add try & catch, but it only led to more errors

```js
const { createWorker } = require('tesseract.js'); 
const worker = createWorker();

function foo() {
  (async () => {
    await worker.load();
    await worker.loadLanguage('eng');
    await worker.initialize('eng');
    await worker.setParameters({
      tessedit_char_whitelist: '123456789'
      // preserve_interword_spaces: '0',
    });
    const { data: { text } } = await worker.recognize('Download.png');
    console.log(text);
    await worker.terminate();
  })();

  setTimeout(foo, 10000);
}

foo();
```

Error message:

```
(node:13988) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of null
    at module.exports (\\node_modules\tesseract.js\src\worker\node\send.js:9:10)
    at \\node_modules\tesseract.js\src\createWorker.js:47:7
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at startJob (\\node_modules\tesseract.js\src\createWorker.js:43:5)
    at Object.load (\\node_modules\tesseract.js\src\createWorker.js:57:5)
    at \\tesseract3.js:28:18
    at Timeout.myFetch [as _onTimeout] (\\tesseract3.js:38:5)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:13988) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 3)        
(node:13988) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:13988) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of null
```

Comment: `tried to add try & catch, but it only led to more errors` perhaps you did it wrong, correct use of try/catch will not produce more errors - also, why not just make `foo` an `async` function, then you woudn't need that async iife

Comment: at what place would you add the catch? it seems I am adding it incorrectly.

Comment: huh? after the try block is where I would put it .... `try { everything currently INSIDE the iife } catch(err) { }`

Comment: just wondering, after `worker.terminate()` would you need to `createWorker` again - can't see `tesseract.js` so it's hard to guess

Comment: I added try catch and it seems there's one less error now, but one remains:

Same behavior. Runs perfectly on the initial run, first Interval is an error: 
Remaining error: 

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of null`

Comment: I suspect it's something in *your* tesseract.js code

Comment: Tesseract is not my code, it's https://www.npmjs.com/package/tesseract.js/v/2.1.1

--- my code is working, it runs perfectly the first iteration, only not able to repeat it..

Comment: oh, sorry ... I misread that require :p

Comment: see, the docs say `Worker.terminate() terminates the worker and cleans up` ... I suspect, as I said an hour ago, you'd need to `createWorker()` again - did you try that suggestion?

Comment: just move `const worker = createWorker();` into the foo function.

Comment: @JaromandaX You have been right, I didn't catch this this earlier. The issue is fixed, thanks alot!!